# Stop content in wrapper from shrinking before the empty space (margin of wrapper) on the left and right of the content is hidden

Tags: html, css, flexbox

As you can see in the snippet below, if you start resizing the browser, the `<div>` element with `class="cities-list"` begins resizing instantly.

What I hope to achieve is have the `<div>` element with `class="cities-list"` not shrink down until there is no more empty space on the left and right of it where the margin of the wrapper used to be.

Am I going about this the wrong way?

```css
*, *:after, *:before {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        text-decoration: none;
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    html {
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    body {
        background-color: #fafafa;
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        line-height: 1.8rem;
    }
    .wrapper {
        width: 70%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
        .nav {
        background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #57cfb0, #2ab5d3);
    }
    .nav-ul {
        display: flex;
    }
    .nav li {
        padding: 11px 30px 11px 0;
        color: #ffffff;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-weight: 500;
    }
    .nav li:nth-last-child(2) {
        margin-left: auto;
    }
    .nav li:last-child {
        padding-right: 0px;
    }
    .cities-list {
        display: flex;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .cities-list p {
        background-color: #ffffff;
        padding: 20px;
        margin: 10px 10px 10px 0px;
        cursor: pointer;
        flex-basis: 49.5%;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<div class="nav">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <ul class='nav-ul'>
            <li>Test 1</li>
            <li>Test 2</li>
            <li>Test 3</li>
            <li>Test 4</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='wrapper'>
    <div class='cities-list'>
        <p>Tokyo, Japan</p>
        <p>London, United Kingdom</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set a min-width to your `.cities-list` and also  `width: 100%` to your wrapper, above some breakpoint like this:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .cities-list-wrapper {
     width: 100%;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
   }

  .cities-list {
    min-width: 1180px;
    max-width: 1180px;
  }
}
```

(I added class `cities-list-wrapper` to your wrapper)

```css
*, *:after, *:before {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        text-decoration: none;
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    html {
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    body {
        background-color: #fafafa;
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        line-height: 1.8rem;
    }
    .wrapper {
        width: 70%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
        .nav {
        background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #57cfb0, #2ab5d3);
    }
    .nav-ul {
        display: flex;
    }
    .nav li {
        padding: 11px 30px 11px 0;
        color: #ffffff;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-weight: 500;
    }
    .nav li:nth-last-child(2) {
        margin-left: auto;
    }
    .nav li:last-child {
        padding-right: 0px;
    }
    .cities-list {
        display: flex;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .cities-list p {
        background-color: #ffffff;
        padding: 20px;
        margin: 10px 10px 10px 0px;
        cursor: pointer;
        flex-basis: 49.5%;
        text-align: center;
    }

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .cities-list-wrapper {
     width: 100%;
   }

  .cities-list {
    min-width: 1180px;
    max-width: 1180px;
    margin: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <ul class='nav-ul'>
            <li>Test 1</li>
            <li>Test 2</li>
            <li>Test 3</li>
            <li>Test 4</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='wrapper cities-list-wrapper'>
    <div class='cities-list'>
        <p>Tokyo, Japan</p>
        <p>London, United Kingdom</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> not shrink down until there is no more empty space on the left and right of it where the margin of the wrapper used to be

Did you mean in the mobile size?
just use media query

```
@media (max-width: 767px){
  .wrapper {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: No, I don't mean that. My wrapper has a width of 70% and my content takes that width, the other 30% is the wrapper's margin. When I start resizing the browser, the 70% part of the wrapper starts resizing, even though there's a lot of free margin space.

Comment: _“When I start resizing the browser, the 70% part of the wrapper starts resizing, even though there's a lot of free margin space.”_ - of course it does, 70% of the width of the parent element _are_ 70% of the width of the parent element. What extra space is available around the element has no influence on that. (That space is 15% on each side, and of course _that_ changes with the overall width as well.)